# Stop LAMP in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, lamp

I use LAMP for testing in local environment. I would like to try AMPPS, but LAMP is interfering with it. Is there any command to stop LAMP ? I would like to know how to start LAMP if my experience with AMPPS doesn't go as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any command to stop LAMP ?

LAMP is not a service but an acronym for Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP.
"Stopping LAMP" is not possible. You can stop 2 components of a LAMP stack: apache and mysql.

```
systemctl stop apache2.service
systemctl stop mysqld
```

and ...

```
systemctl is-enabled apache2.service
systemctl is-enabled mysqld
```

will show if it is running.

Linux and PHP are not services so do not need to be stopped.

> I would like to know how to start LAMP if my experience with AMPPS doesn't go as expected.

Now for a problem or a misinterpretation from your side:

AMPPS is Apache, MySQL, MongoDB, PHP, Perl, Python. I do not see any conflicts with LAMP: what you need to do is install Mongodb since AMPPS = LAMP + MongoDB. Perl, Python are native to Linux so all you are missing is MongoDB.

So

```
sudo apt install lamp-server^
```

and following the [installation guide to MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) is installing AMPPS.